# Restler 3 - Setup configuration

Tags: php, xampp, restler

I'm using XAMPP that has PHP 5.3.1, with restler structure in htdocs folder

In my htdocs folder, I have the index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/restler.php';
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;

$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('Say'); // repeat for more
$r->handle(); //serve the response
```

and say.php

```
<?php
class Say {

    /*
    * @url GET /
    */
    function hello($to='world') {
        return "Hello $to!";
    }

    function hi($to) {
        return  "Hi $to!";
    }
}
```

In the browser, I put

> localhost/index.php/Say

or

> localhost/index.php/Say/hello

it gives me the following message

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function Luracast\Restler\stream_resolve_include_path() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Luracast/Restler/AutoLoader.php on line 143

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: stream_resolve_include_path is only available on php 5.3.2 but restler should work on 5.3 and above. We will sort this out. Meanwhile can you try upgrading PHP and see if it works? You may follow the [autoloader conversation](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/issues/72) in github

Comment: That did the trick. Changed to AMPSS that supports PHP 5.4 and worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the PHP version. Changed from XAMPP to AMPSS that supports PHP 5.4 and its working now

Answer (score 0):

don't know if it helps but have you tried to
write Say in lowercase?

`localhost/index.php/say`

Your code looks good to me...

Cu
Inge

Answer (score 0):

Restler 3 is PHP 5.3 and the function `stream_resolve_include_path` will be defined with versions 5.3.2 and later.